# Struct pointer free causes error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

i have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char* type;
    char* address;
    int area, price;
}Offer;
```

and these two functions:

```
Offer* initOffer(char* type, char* address, int area, int price)
{
    Offer* p;
    p = (Offer*)malloc(sizeof(Offer));
    p->type = (char*)malloc(sizeof(type));
    p->address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(address));
    strcpy(p->type, type);
    strcpy(p->address, address);
    p->area = area;
    p->price = price;
    return p;
}

void destroyOffer(Offer* offer)
{
    free(offer->type);
    free(offer->address);
    free(offer);
}
```

The problem occurs when i call destroyOffer, I have no idea why, but when I run the code, I have an error saying: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED. If i remove these 2 lines, it works fine but I suppose that the memory is not cleaned properly:

```
free(offer->type);
free(offer->address);
```

Comment: If you omit the frees, you are leaking memory — you're correct that the memory won't be cleaned up properly.  And your principal problem is correctly diagnosed by user3121023.

Comment: free() should only be used after malloc() has been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

```
p->type = (char*)malloc(sizeof(type));   // That's just the size of a pointer
p->address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(address)); // Same problem.
```

After that, the lines:

```
strcpy(p->type, type);
strcpy(p->address, address);
```

end up writing over memory they are not supposed to. That leads to undefined behavior.

You need:

```
p->type = malloc(strlen(type)+1);
p->address = malloc(strlen(address)+1);
```

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

You can also use `strdup` if it is supported by your compiler. If so, your code can be simplified to:

```
p->type = strdup(type);
p->address = strdup(address);
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I am reading right now the topic related to cast.

Comment: Also, can you please tell me why is it strlen(type) +1 and not simply strlen(type)?

Comment: `strlen` returns the length of the string that does not include the terminating null character. You need the additional character for that.

Comment: Ah, the asciiz, i got it. Thank you, again!